# DocuSign SOAP API - Set Tab Fonts does not Change Font

Tags: fonts, tabs, font-size, docusignapi

I have a PDF document with Arial 10 font and for DocuSign signature, name and date tabs, I am setting the same fonts, but when signing the document, the fonts do not seem to get changed.

I am using SOAP API with C# on Windows. How do I change the font of tabs? Thanks.

```
                        tab3 = new DocuSignAPI.Tab();
                        tab3.RecipientID = rcpt1.ID;
                        tab3.PageNumber = "1";
                        tab3.DocumentID = docId;
                        tab3.Type = DocuSignAPI.TabTypeCode.SignHere;
                        tab3.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
                        tab3.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = "Signature:";
                        tab3.AnchorTabItem.Unit = DocuSignAPI.UnitTypeCode.Pixels;
                        tab3.AnchorTabItem.IgnoreIfNotPresent = true;
                        tab3.AnchorTabItem.UnitSpecified = true;
                        tab3.AnchorTabItem.YOffset = 0;
                        tab3.AnchorTabItem.XOffset = 200;
                        tab3.Font = DocuSignAPI.Font.Arial;
                        tab3.FontSize = DocuSignAPI.FontSize.Size10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to specify two more parameters. And that fixed it.

```
                        tab3.FontSpecified = true;
                        tab3.FontSizeSpecified = true;
```